# Optimizing MySQL Query - search condition on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am using MySQL 5.7.25 and this is the query I am trying to optimize:

```
SELECT a.contract,
       a.phone_number_1,
       a.phone_number_2,
       a.phone_number_3,
       a.phone_number_4,
       a.phone_number_5
  FROM tempdb.customer_crm a
 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(a.contract) = 12
   AND (
         a.contract in (SELECT contract_final FROM tempdb.relevant_contracts)
         OR a.phone_number_1 in (SELECT phone_number FROM tempdb.relevant_numbers_1)
         OR a.phone_number_2 in (SELECT phone_number FROM tempdb.relevant_numbers_2)
         OR a.phone_number_3 in (SELECT phone_number FROM tempdb.relevant_numbers_3)
         OR a.phone_number_4 in (SELECT phone_number FROM tempdb.relevant_numbers_4)
         OR a.phone_number_5 in (SELECT phone_number FROM tempdb.relevant_numbers_5)
       );
```

**customer_crm** table has 5 different phone numbers in 5 columns. I need to filter all the records where any of the 5 phone numbers exists in table **relevant_numbers**. I have made 5 copies of table **relevant_numbers** as I can only use TEMPORARY tables (which cannot be opened more than once in MySQL). The number of records in:

- customer_crm: 80 Million
- relevant_numbers: 63 Thousand
- relevant_contracts: 93 Thousand
- Result of the query: 100 Thousand

This query takes too long. I have shaved off a few minutes using (phone number length condition):

```
SELECT a.contract,
       a.phone_number_1,
       a.phone_number_2,
       a.phone_number_3,
       a.phone_number_4,
       a.phone_number_5
  FROM tempdb.customer_crm a
 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(a.contract) = 12
   AND (
         a.contract in (SELECT contract_final FROM tempdb.relevant_contracts)
         OR (CHAR_LENGTH(a.phone_number_1) > 9 AND a.phone_number_1 in (SELECT phone_number FROM tempdb.relevant_numbers_1))
         OR (CHAR_LENGTH(a.phone_number_2) > 9 AND a.phone_number_2 in (SELECT phone_number FROM tempdb.relevant_numbers_2))
         OR (CHAR_LENGTH(a.phone_number_3) > 9 AND a.phone_number_3 in (SELECT phone_number FROM tempdb.relevant_numbers_3))
         OR (CHAR_LENGTH(a.phone_number_4) > 9 AND a.phone_number_4 in (SELECT phone_number FROM tempdb.relevant_numbers_4))
         OR (CHAR_LENGTH(a.phone_number_5) > 9 AND a.phone_number_5 in (SELECT phone_number FROM tempdb.relevant_numbers_5))
       );
```

It still takes about 10 minutes. I have tried using EXISTS condition instead of IN and it takes even longer. I have also tried using left join which also takes longer. All the columns are individually indexed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why can you only use temporary tables? Why don't you use joins? Which indexes exist on the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OR` is a performance killer.  So is `IN ( SELECT ... )`.

The query as it stands is going to do a full table scan of 80M rows, and do lookups into the temp tables.  Those secondary lookups will be only 1 row if you go to the effort of indexing your temp tables, or 63K rows otherwise -- That would add up to 25 *trillion* lookups.  It might finish this year.

**Plan A:**  Turn `OR` into `UNION`:

```
    (  SELECT  cc.id
            FROM  tempdb.customer_crm AS cc
            JOIN  tempdb.relevant_contracts AS rc
            WHERE  cc.contract = rc.contract 
    )  UNION  
    (  SELECT  cc.id
            FROM  tempdb.customer_crm AS cc
            JOIN  tempdb.relevant_numbers_1 AS rn
            WHERE  cc.phone_number_1 = rn.phone_number 
    )  UNION
    (  SELECT  cc.id
            FROM  tempdb.customer_crm AS cc
            JOIN  tempdb.relevant_numbers_2 AS rn
            WHERE  cc.phone_number_2 = rn.phone_number 
    )  UNION
    (  SELECT  cc.id
            FROM  tempdb.customer_crm AS cc
            JOIN  tempdb.relevant_numbers_3 AS rn
            WHERE  cc.phone_number_3 = rn.phone_number 
    )  UNION  
    (  SELECT  cc.id
            FROM  tempdb.customer_crm AS cc
            JOIN  tempdb.relevant_numbers_4 AS rn
            WHERE  cc.phone_number_4 = rn.phone_number 
    )  UNION  
    (  SELECT  cc.id
            FROM  tempdb.customer_crm AS cc
            JOIN  tempdb.relevant_numbers_5 AS rn
            WHERE  cc.phone_number_5 = rn.phone_number 
    )
```

I am assuming that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `customer_crm`.  You will need these indexes on `customer_crm`:

```
INDEX(contract, id)
INDEX(phone_number_1, id)
INDEX(phone_number_2, id)
INDEX(phone_number_3, id)
INDEX(phone_number_4, id)
INDEX(phone_number_5, id)
```

Use the above query as a subquery, `JOIN` that back to `customer_crm` to get whatever columns you really need.

That will be on the order of 1 million actions -- *much* less.

The check for length=12 can come later as a minor annoyance.

**Plan B:**  Don't use 5 columns.

It is usually a bad schema design to have an array of things spread across multiple columns or packed together in a single column.  Instead, have another table with (at least) 2 columns:  the `number` and the `id` to join back to the main table.

With `INDEX(number)`, it won't matter that it has 5*80M rows.

**Plan C:**  Would you care to back up to before creating the temp tables; other optmizations may be possible.

Comment: Thank you Rick. Your Plan A did wonders. Query execution time reduced about 6 times. As this is client db I cannot implement Plan B or C. I am accepting it as solution.

Answer (score 2):

> customer_crm table has 5 different phone numbers in 5 columns. I need to filter all the records where any of the 5 phone numbers exists in table relevant_numbers.

Instead of checking individually each phone number in `relevant_numbers`, why not use `exists` with an `in` condition?

```
select c.*
from tempdb.customer_crm c
where 
    exists (
        select 1
        from tempdb.relevant_contracts o
        where o.contract_final = c.contract 
    )
    or exists (
        select 1
        from tempdb.relevant_numbers n
        where n.phone_number in (
            c.phone_number_1,
            c.phone_number_2,
            c.phone_number_3,
            c.phone_number_4,
            c.phone_number_5
        )
    )
```

For performance, you can try the following indexes:

```
customer_crm(
    contract, 
    phone_number_1,
    phone_number_2,
    phone_number_3,
    phone_number_4,
    phone_number_5
)
relevant_contracts(contract_final)
relevant_numbers (phone_number)
```

I am also unsure that the checks on the length of `contract` is beneficial: using a function here makes the query non SARGable (ie prevents the use of an index).

Comment: contract length is a requirement. i added the optional length checks on phone numbers and it seemed to reduce time. let me try your suggestions and get back. Also, it should be "OR EXISTS" instead of AND. Right?

Comment: @Imtiaz: what is the datatype of column `contract`: string or numeric?

Comment: contract is varchar(20), so are all the phone numbers. I can't change the original tables as they are customer's. I can however change types in my temporary tables.

Comment: Thanks @GMB for your help. I tried your suggestions but the query execution time remained in the same ballpark.